# Converting a Hardware description language to a functional programming language

Tags: pl.programming-languages

I am looking for some guidelines on converting a Hardware description language such as VHDL or Verilog to a Typed Language. The reason I want to do this is to formally verify a hardware whose behavioral description is written in HDL.

Comment: It might be easier to give a meaningful answer to your question if you give a bit of context. What are the goals of such a conversion? What properties should the conversion preserve?

Comment: Look at the work of Koen Claessen on Lava or Geraint Jones on Ruby.

Comment: Thank you Dave. I am working along the lines of Lava and Ruby.

Comment: Martin. My intention is to formally verify a hardware circuit and for that reason I want to convert HDL to a platform where I can use formal verification tools.

Comment: Please edit your question so that people can understand what you are asking without reading comments.

Answer (score 3):

You could write an interpreter for VHDL or Verilog in e.g. Coq or Isabelle/HOL and then prove that translated hardware descriptions do the right thing. I know that people have done this, at least for fragments of the hardware description languages, see e.g. [A Formal Executable Semantics of Verilog](http://fsl.cs.illinois.edu/index.php/A_Formal_Executable_Semantics_of_Verilog).  Companies like Intel or AMD formally verify (parts of) the design of their chips. Have a look at [Roope Kaivola](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/pers/hd/k/Kaivola:Roope)'s work.

Answer (score 2):

[This work on "HML"](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=486388&tag=1) does the reverse - it compiles an ML-like hardware description language to VHDL - but it might offer some insights on how to relate constructs in these languages.